# Keep getting a logic error that reduces my array output to a bunch o zeros

Tags: java, javascript, arrays

So as per usual I've got a pretty bad logic error in my code that my compiler isn't catching and thus my output is not returning the values i need and i was wondering if someone could give me a nudge in the right direction as to how to solve this pesky error. But before you guys get to that it might help if i explain whats going on a bit . so in the main I am trying to assign value 'x' aa array of numbers that gets carried over to getAllEvens in another file but somewhere along the way to the output screen the value changes get negated or didn't happen at all and all i get are zeros. 
i would really appreciate any help or suggestions on this but please try to keep onsets along the lines of my code or at least not use too many advanced methods as I'm trying to keep this in line with a lab I'm doing for school. so now on to the code

code in the main

```
`int[] x = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14};
 int[] x = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14};
 int[] y = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
 int[] z = {2,10,20,21,23,24,40,55,60,61};

 System.out.println("Odds - " + Arrays.toString(OddsAndEvens.getAllOdds(x)));
 System.out.println("Evens - " + Arrays.toString(OddsAndEvens.getAllEvens(x)));
```

code in the other file

```
private static int[] cf = new int[20];
public static int countEm(int[] array, boolean odd)
{
    cf=array;
    return 0;
}
public static int[] getAllEvens(int[] array)
{
        int[]vegeta = new int[20];
        int VegetaScouterCount = 0;
        int[] XboxThreeYearOld = new int[20];
        for(int f : cf)
        {

            if(array[f]%2==0)
            {
                vegeta[VegetaScouterCount]=cf[f];
                VegetaScouterCount++;
                XboxThreeYearOld = Arrays.copyOfRange(vegeta, 0, VegetaScouterCount);
            }
            XboxThreeYearOld = Arrays.copyOfRange(vegeta, 0, VegetaScouterCount);
        }
        return XboxThreeYearOld;
}
```

(please ignore the "hip" Slang)

output i get

```
Odds - []
Evens - [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

ouput i want

```
Odds - []
Evens - [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
```

any way id appreciate any help in pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I really appreciate all the feedback on this question as i was not expecting all the help I've gotten but now i do see that i have indeed set all my values to zero and now i feel like a total idiot any way thanks for the nudge in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized your `cf` array, so Java will automatically assign default values to it, meaning each element will have the value zero.

Also, you're using `cf` (which is entirely composed of zeros) to check whether a number is even, so it is `0 % 2`.

Also, you're assigning the elements of `cf` to `vegeta`, which is turn is copied into `XboxThreeYearOld`, which is the returned value. So, in consequence, your returned array will be populated with zeroes.

To get around your issue, use the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
        vegeta[VegetaScouterCount] = array[i];
        VegetaScouterCount++;
        XboxThreeYearOld = Arrays.copyOfRange(vegeta, 0, VegetaScouterCount);
    }
    XboxThreeYearOld = Arrays.copyOfRange(vegeta, 0, VegetaScouterCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This,

```
for(int f : cf)
{
  if(array[f]%2==0)
  {
```

Accesses the value at `f` of `array`. I think you wanted to check if `f` is even.

```
for(int f : array)
{
  if(f%2==0)
```

To really fix your code, I would start by writing a method to count the even values. Like,

```
static int countEvens(int[] arr) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i : arr) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Then you can use that to get your odds and evens like

```
static int[] getAllEvens(int[] array) {
    int[] out = new int[countEvens(array)];
    int pos = 0;
    for (int f : array) {
        if (f % 2 == 0) {
            out[pos++] = f;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

and then

```
static int[] getAllOdds(int[] array) {
    int[] out = new int[array.length - countEvens(array)];
    int pos = 0;
    for (int f : array) {
        if (f % 2 != 0) {
            out[pos++] = f;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much i appreciate it it probably would have helped if i removed all that hip slang but now i understand what i did wrong thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is not real requirement for an array it might be easier using a growing collection like Sets or Lists. But using the given structure you are using the for each loop incorrectly.

The variable f is not an index but the value of cf for every position. And because cf is initialized with length 20 and zero filled it will always return 0.

try with a traditional for loop i.e. `for (int i=0; i<cf.length;i++){ // do work here }` and check output.

There might be other logical errors the compiler won't catch because it's not a syntax or type issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. before you print the `odds and evens`  you must call `countem()` method
2. instead  just change `vegeta[VegetaScouterCount]=cf[f];`  to `vegeta[VegetaScouterCount]=array[f];`
   the problem  is that your array `cf`  was just instanciated  with size of 20  BUT  all of the indexes are `0`  by default until you tell it otherwise